# Computing u32 hash with FxHasher fast

Tags: rust, hash

I've been recently experimenting with different hash functions in Rust. Started off with the `fasthash` [crate](https://github.com/flier/rust-fasthash), where many algorithms are implemented; e.g., murmur3 is then called as

```
let hval = murmur3::hash32_with_seed(&tmp_read_buff, 123 as u32);
```

This works very fast (e.g., few seconds for `100000000` short inputs). I also stumbled upon FxHash, the algorithm used a lot internally in Firefox (at least initially?). I rolled my version of hashing a byte array with this algorithm as follows

```
use rustc_hash::FxHasher;
use std::hash::Hasher;

fn hash_with_fx(read_buff: &[u8]) -> u64 {

    let mut hasher = FxHasher::default();
    for el in read_buff {
        hasher.write_u8(*el);
    }
    return hasher.finish();
}
```

This works, however, it's about **5x slower**. I'd really like to know if I'm missing something apparent here/how could I achieve similar or better speeds to `fasthash`'s e.g., murmur3. My intuition is that with FxHash, the core operation is [very simple](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-hash/blob/master/src/lib.rs),

```
 self.hash = self.hash.rotate_left(5).bitxor(i).wrapping_mul(K);
```

hence it should be one of the fastest.

Comment: As always, are you running release build?

Comment: From the documentation you linked: _"the speed of the hash function itself is much higher because it works on up to 8 bytes at a time."_. But you aren't taking advantage of that because you are processing one byte at a time.

Comment: You could fix yours to hash 8 bytes at a time, something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd03923a80144dc0898856c3505c1ac8).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes, they are all compiled as `--release`. Thanks @PeterHall, this is very neat, will try it out!

Comment: @PeterHall adapted your version a bit (did not consider borrows of the remainder), this is lightning fast! https://gist.github.com/89256e97cdfcca53ade3bc28f55bef1c Consider submitting this as the answer, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FxHasher` documentation mentions that:

> the speed of the hash function itself is much higher because it works on up to 8 bytes at a time.

But your algorithm completely removes this possibility because you are processing each byte individually. You can make it a lot faster by hashing in chunks of 8 bytes.

```
fn hash_with_fx(read_buff: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    let mut hasher = FxHasher::default();
    let mut chunks = read_buff.chunks_exact(8);
    for bytes in &mut chunks {
        // unwrap is ok because `chunks_exact` provides the guarantee that
        // the `bytes` slice is exactly the requested length 
        let int = u64::from_be_bytes(bytes.try_into().unwrap());
        hasher.write_u64(int);
    }
    for byte in chunks.remainder() {
        hasher.write_u8(*byte);
    }
    hasher.finish()
}
```

For very small inputs (especially for numbers like 7 bytes) it may introduce a small extra overhead compared with your original code. But, for larger inputs, it ought to be significantly faster.

---

**Bonus material**

It should be possible to remove a few extra instructions in the loop by using `unwrap_unchecked` instead of `unwrap`. It's completely sound to do so in this case, but it may not be worth introducing unsafe code into your codebase. I would measure the difference before deciding to include unsafe code.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into `unwrap_unchecked` too, interesting.